# Using Find Window and can't fix the warning for null error

Tags: c#

I can not make this code work without warning, can someone help me?

I am trying to close Excel while clicking 'don't save' button automatically after Excel prompts it:

> Warning
> CS8625 Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.
> flatui1 C:\Users\pc\source\repos\closeexcel\Program.cs    43
> Active "excelWindow = FindWindow(null, "Microsoft Excel")"

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const uint WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Close Excel.exe process
        CloseExcelProcess();

        // Wait for the Excel prompt window and click "Don't Save"
        WaitForAndClickDontSave();
    }

    static void CloseExcelProcess()
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");

        foreach (Process process in processes)
        {
            process.CloseMainWindow();

            if (!process.WaitForExit(5000))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
        }
    }

    static void WaitForAndClickDontSave()
    {
        IntPtr excelWindow = IntPtr.Zero;

        while (excelWindow == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            excelWindow = FindWindow(null, "Microsoft Excel");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        IntPtr dontSaveButton = FindWindow("#32770", "Microsoft Excel");
        dontSaveButton = FindWindowEx(dontSaveButton, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Don't Save");

        if (dontSaveButton != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            SendMessage(dontSaveButton, 0xf5, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);
}
```

I also tried with UIautomation and can't get rid of this warning:

> Warning CS8600
> Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
> flatui1 C:\Users\pc\source\repos\Program.cs  61
> Active  "  InvokePattern invokePattern = button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;"

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Automation;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find the Excel window
        AutomationElement excelWindow = FindExcelWindow();

        if (excelWindow != null)
        {
            // Attach an event handler for window closing
            Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowClosedEvent,
                excelWindow, TreeScope.Element,
                (sender, e) =&gt;
                {
                    // Find the "Don't Save" button and click it
                    AutomationElement dontSaveButton = FindDontSaveButton();
                    if (dontSaveButton != null)
                    {
                        InvokeButton(dontSaveButton);
                    }
                });

            // Keep the program running
            Console.WriteLine("Listening for Excel window close...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Excel window not found.");
        }
    }

    static AutomationElement FindExcelWindow()
    {
        string excelClassName = "XLMAIN";
        string excelProcessName = "EXCEL";

        PropertyCondition classCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, excelClassName);
        PropertyCondition processCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, excelProcessName);

        AndCondition condition = new AndCondition(classCondition, processCondition);

        return AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, condition);
    }

    static AutomationElement FindDontSaveButton()
    {
        string dontSaveName = "Don't Save";

        PropertyCondition nameCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, dontSaveName);

        return AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, nameCondition);
    }

    static void InvokeButton(AutomationElement button)
    {
        InvokePattern invokePattern = button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
        invokePattern?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have nullable checks on. Then allow null values in the method declaration explicitly: `static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string? lpClassName, string lpWindowName)`

Comment: excelWindow = static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string? lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

error - Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1002 ; expected ButtonClickAutomation C:\Users\source\repos\ButtonClickAutomation\ButtonClickAutomation\Program.cs 47 Active
Error CS1525 Invalid expression term 'static' ButtonClickAutomation C:\Users\\source\repos\ButtonClickAutomation\ButtonClickAutomation\Program.cs 47 Active

Comment: No. this is not what I meant. Just add the ? sign to the 4th line of code you posted.

Comment: alright, I put the ? and the code removed the warnings and ran without errors but it did not click 'don't save' button :( Excel still exited forcefully without clicking 'dont save' button at exit prompt :( :(